# How to calculate the percentage of number of rows using excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Input File:**

```
dsf96lin11  Available   2/12    42% 
asf64lin5   Available   6/12    4 %     
asf256lin8  Available   3/6     49 %        
dsf96lin15  Available   4/16    15 %    
dsf192lin20 Available   1/16    9 %     
dsf32lin31  Available   0/8     2 %
```

**My query:**

1.How to calculate the overall percentage for the column 4 using excel sheet.

**Expected output:**

1.overall percentage of column 4 and it should be averaged by number of rows

**I tired the following thing:**

=sum(c1:c6) but it only sums the rows.

And am not clear is it right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AVERAGE(D1:D6)` and set cell formatting to percentage